# YOLO (Real-Time Object Detection) running as API

Tags: object, networking, time, detection, vision

I was wondering if someone knows about a project that provides [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) as API service. I need to use image detection with object coordinates but I do not want to develop API backend.

Thank you, David